# How can I tell a quicksort algorithm that it should terminate?

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, quicksort

Ok, so I've just started to learn about sorting algorithms in school. I think I know the concept of quicksort pretty well as I can perform on it a piece of paper. However, with a piece of paper, I know when to stop and that's when the array is sorted. But if I check the array all the time to see if it is sorted, that defies the purpose of quicksort which (I think) is not to check if it's sorted many many times with it's recursion. Do I have to just keep recursing it down to when there is only 1 element left in the array when it is by definition sorted or is there some other way to terminate it?

Comment: Recursion needs to guarantee that with each recursion the size of the problem is getting smaller (quicksort does that by partitioning), and also having a stop condition. So yes, you don't need to check if it's sorted. In fact, you can't check if it's sorted in a recursion since it's only sorted after all the recursions are completed.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to just keep recursing it down to when there is only 1 element left in the array when it is by definition sorted or is there some other way to terminate it?

Yes, that is exactly how quicksort should terminate.

Comment: For the pointers that are on 2 sides of the pivot, should I compare and then if they're both on the right side move both of them or should I move just one of the pointers or it really doesn't matter?

Comment: @DengJohnny I'm not sure what you mean. You should post a new question with some code to make it more concrete.

Comment: @DengJohnny Just edit your question and provide more information.  You can even change the title.

Comment: @N0ob - You don't mention what partition scheme is used. In your other question, it appears you are attempting to implement Hoare partition scheme, in which case the pivot and/or elements == pivot can end up anywhere after a partition step. The "pointers" (indexes) are to the first and last elements of a sub-array to be partitioned, and after a partition step, a local variable will "point" to the split for elements <= pivot and elements >= pivot. There's no guarantee that any element is in it's sorted position until a recursive call's parameters represent a single element.

Comment: @N0ob - so continuing, calling the local variable that gets decremented "split", then after a partition step, two recursive calls are made, quicksort(..., first, split) and quicksort(..., split+1, last). Eventually, first == split, and (split+1) == last, both cases that represent single elements.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you need to make the checks you mention does not mean it is inefficient.  This is no different than `selection sorts` or `bubble sorts` which also have to check various conditions and swap elements.  The idea is that the `quicksort` does not need to make as many checks and is thus faster.

Why not put in sufficient print statements to monitor what you are doing and compare that to what you arrived at on paper.

Comment: That depends on what the check is. Something like `is_sorted()` is `O(n)` and not necessary for a correctly implemented quicksort.